# Strings, Decimals and Null in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the code snippet below that I am trying to work with.

```
decimal preTestAir = decimal.Parse(AirPreTestTextBox.Value);
```

`preTestAir` is a `decimal` and needs to remain a `decimal` for being sent to the database. This cannot change. What I am trying to do is determine if `AirPreTestTextBox.Value` is null, if it is, assign it the `decimal` value of `0.00` and then assign it to the `decimal` `preTestAir`. The code above works great as long as there is some numeric value in the text box. What if there isn't a value in the text box? The app crashes. How can I determine if `AirPreTestTextBox.Value` is null and assign a value if it is all in one line? The reason for the one line is because I have almost 100 lines of code that will need to be formatted in this fashion.  I've tried using operators like `??` which won't work with decimals that aren't the nullable type. Can anyone help? Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy enough with a ternary.

```
decimal preTestAir = String.IsNullOrEmpty(AirPreTestTextBox.Value) ? 0 : decimal.Parse(AirPreTestTextBox.Value);
```

Its *very* unlikely that a text box would hold a `null` string, its much more likely that its empty.

Comment: @GreenDeveloper `0.00` is a `double`, not a `decimal`. And `0` is an `int`, but ints are implicitly convertible to the `decimal` type. You could use `0m`, `0.0m`, or `0.00m`. The `m` is for `decimal`. The number of trailing zeroes matters, but depending on your use you can probably use any of them. The int `0` becomes the `decimal` `0m` without trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the conditional operator:

```
decimal preTestAir = AirPreTestTextBox.Value == null ? 
                     0.0m :
                     decimal.Parse(AirPreTestTextBox.Value);
```

Comment: Actually, It threw me this error. Does it make sense?

An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 4):

The null coalescing operator (??) is your friend here. Use

```
(AirPreTestTextBox.Value ?? "0.00")
```

Answer (score 1):

just use try parse.... it will handle any non convertible to decimal

```
decimal preTestAir;
if(!deciaml.TryParse(AirPreTestTextBox.Value, out preTestAir))
{
  // handle the fact it couldn't convert if you like...
}
```